# ASP.NET Core can't get object from body

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-2.0

Code:

```
[HttpPost("user/register")]
public IActionResult Register([FromBody] User user)
{
    if (user?.Name is null || user?.Password is null)
    {
        return BadRequest(new {message = "User is null and/or name and password are not provided"});
    }
    else
    {
         // Add to db
         return Json(user);
    }
}
```

Also the User class:

```
public class User
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public string Role { get; set; }
}
```

---

It should basically get a user and add it to the database. I tried sending this json:

```
{ "Name": "Batman", "Password": "IronmanSucks"}
```

The app caught the request, but the user object was null. I also tried with:

```
{ "user": { "Name": "Batman", "Password": "IronmanSucks"} }
```

But according to this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-web-api), the first json should have worked fine.

Here is a [link](https://documenter.getpostman.com/view/2237151/rimotr/6n5ysyV) to an example http request in postman

---

Does this have to do with the headers or is it a bug in .NET Core 2.0?

Comment: Could you please add the structure of your `User` class?

Comment: If the Json doesn't perfectly match to the `User` object, the object will be null. So it is important to include the class in the question.

Comment: When not using the FromBody attribute, it crashes with code 500

Comment: @MitkoRusev When you debug, the output window will show you details about the unhandled exceptin. What does it say when it throws the 500?

Comment: @MitkoRusev Maybe the Guid (id) doesn't accept a null value. Have you tried to set a value in the json from postman? (like "E796E7EB-EB5A-485C-A1A0-26C5F5F242C1"). Or try changing the `Guid` type to `Guid?`.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto You were right. When not using the attribute, the object doesn't make it into the action, but the problem is not having a parameterless constructor. When adding such, it worked both with the attribute and without it. I have it there because I need Swagger documentation.

Comment: @MitkoRusev glad you could get the actual error. Notice that it's almost never required to specify [FromBody] unless you want to strictly allow that parameter to only be binded through the body. And the output window is your friend. You should post an answer so that it gets registered

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto So, [FromBody] only restricts other ways of input

Answer (score 1):

This can only happen if the type does not have a parameterless constructor, thus this can be simply fixed by adding such.

Comment: @MatthieuCharbonnier you do need a parameterless constructor, implicit if no constructors at all or explicit if there's a parameterful constructor already.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that the Model is coming up as invalid hence why it is null.
You should try adding a `[BindNever]` attribute into the User class for the `Role` and `Guid` properties, seeing as you aren't using them.

If that doesn't work you may try using extended classes like so:

```
public class User
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
}

public class DataUser : User
{
    public Guid Id { get; set }
    public string Role { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using *MVC Core* instead of *MVC*, make sure you add *Json Formaters* (from **Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.Json**). In your **Startup.cs**:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services
        .AddMvcCore()
        .AddJsonFormatters();
}
```

This should help the **[FromBody]** to de-serialize your Post content